# Python help defining a list

Tags: python

What is the best way to define a list that takes all numbers that are typed into input and prints only the numbers in that list divisible by 3?

```
def numbers(list):
    #code for defining a list
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
for n in numbers:
    if n % 3 == 0:
        print n
```

The 3rd line divides the number by 3, and if the remainder is 0 (making it divisible by 3), it prints the number.

Answer (score 0):

This method simply takes 2 lists, `x` being the list with what you choose to input as the limit to the number you want, and the `y` list returns the results for which numbers in `x` can be divided by 3.

```py
x = []
y = []
for i in range(70):
    x.append(i)

for i in x:
    if i % 3 == 0:
        y.append(i)
   
print(y)
```

Comment: What seems to be your issue? This code returns a list of whole numbers divisible by 3 which are less than 70. That is `[0, 3, ..., 69] `.

Answer (score -2):

```
x = []
n = input("enter length:")
for i in range(1, int(n)): 
     k=input("enter value:") 
     x.append(k) 
for j in x:
     if int(j) % 3 == 0:
     print(j)
```

Check this code if it helps you.[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYw8V.png)